# Grub Rescue - the laptop won't boot at all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

First of all I'm italian, so I apologize for my bad english.

Second, i have a big problem. I have a new Sony Vaio Pro 13 (so, it's an ultrabook WITHOUT the CD drive), which had Windows 8 pre installed. I needed to install Ubuntu in dual boot for university purposes. So, i shrinked the win partition and created a new partition, and from a bootable usb stick i created a swap partition and an ext4 partition, and installed ubuntu. Due to several failures, i used the Boot-repair tool, which installed the grub 2 bootloader, from which i could start ubuntu and windows. Anyway ubuntu didn't start, it showed me an error, but this is not the problem. The problem is that, due to this error, i decided to try again (because maybe i did something wrong), so i logged into windows and deleted the two linux partitions, creating an unallocated space, and rebooted with the usb stick on.
But i got stuck in the "grub rescue".

I looked in the internet, but i found nothing, because

1. the booting order is FIRST the ssd drive and second the usb stick (when i installed ubuntu before, i loaded the usb stick from a Sony Uefi-like menu, which had 4 options, and one of them was "boot fom usb");
2. i don't have a cd/dvd drive, because the laptop is an ultrabook;
3. i don't have linux installed on the drive anymore (because as i said above, i deleted the partitions).

What can i do? In some days i have an university exam and i need to get to my documents as soon as i can..

Comment: What do you mean by "I got stuck in the grub rescue"? The live distro does not boot at all?

Comment: Exactly, the live distro does not boot at all..

Comment: You can add the answer you typed in as your 'edit' as an actual answer to your question and then accept that. This way your question is no longer listed as unanswered and others can benefit from your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

For those who has a Sony Vaio Pro 13: there's an "Assist" button on the top of the keyboard. Press it while the laptop is off, and it will turn on loading a completely dedicated loader and partition. From there, you can access bios settings, load from usb, and do other stuffs that will help you getting out of your problem. Well done Sony, well done.

Comment: Good for you! Don't forget to backup your important files from now on. You should try to access your backup from another computer so you know how you do it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Windows does not boot? If you can boot the ubuntu desktop from your
usb stick, perhaps you can access your files that way

Comment: No, i can't even access ubuntu desktop, because the usb sticks doesn't load, due to the bios settings (which is uefi, so i don't know how to open the bios settings without using win) which make the ssd load first, and so the grub rescue window.